# Failing to display json array in html table

Tags: javascript, jquery, json, ajax

I am using a php script to produce a json array. The json array is retrieved by a jquery ajax script which then tries to read it and embed it in an html table. However, I'm stuck since it keeps producing 'undefined' data in the table. I want to display the information of the json array in my table after the ajax returns successfully. Please help...

The JSON Array format

```
[{"fullname":"Frank Robsinga","gender":"Male","email":"n\/a","phone":"n\/a","status":"1"}]
```

The javascript

```
<script>
$("#lookup").click(function() {

var key = $("#search").val();

$.ajax({
    type : 'POST',
    url : 'scripts/search-user-script.php',
    data : {
        key : key
    },
    success : function(obj) {

        $("#usersdata").html("");
        for (var i = 0; i < obj.length; i++) {
            var tr = "<tr>";
            var td0 = "<td>" + (i + 1) + "</td>";
            var td1 = "<td>" + obj[i]["fullname"] + "</td>";
            var td2 = "<td>" + obj[i]["gender"] + "</td>";
            var td3 = "<td>" + obj[i]["email"] + "</td>";
            var td4 = "<td>" + obj[i]["phone"] + "</td>";
            var td5 = "<td>" + obj[i]["status"] + "</td></tr>";
            $("#usersdata").append(tr + td0 + td1 + td2 + td3 + td4 + td5);

        }

    }
});
// .ajax
});
</script>
```

A screenshot of the results
[image]

Comment: Just try with $obj[$i]->fullname

Comment: @Manmohan javascript is not PHP.... `obj[i].fullname`

Comment: What is problem of your code?

Comment: @Mohammad `obj[i]["status"]` will return undefined it is missing `.` and it has `[""]` in `obj[i].status`

Comment: @Manmohan: Tried that but it still failed.

Comment: When I chech my console, it has this message "Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'length' of undefined"

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```js
var obj = [{
  "fullname": "Frank Robsinga",
  "gender": "Male",
  "email": "n\/a",
  "phone": "n\/a",
  "status": "1"
}]

for (var i = 0; i < obj.length; i++) {
  console.log(obj[i].fullname)
  console.log(obj[i].gender)
  console.log(obj[i].email)
  console.log(obj[i].phone)
  console.log(obj[i].status)
}
```

```html
<table id='usersdata'></table>
```

you have to `.` also remove `[""]` like `obj[i].status`

you ajax should look like :

```
$.ajax({
    type : 'POST',
    url : 'scripts/search-user-script.php',
    dataType:'json',
    data : {
        key : key
    },
    success : function(obj) {

        $("#usersdata").html("");
        for (var i = 0; i < obj.length; i++) {
            var tr = "<tr>";
            var td0 = "<td>" + (i + 1) + "</td>";
            var td1 = "<td>" + obj[i].fullname + "</td>";
            var td2 = "<td>" + obj[i].gender + "</td>";
            var td3 = "<td>" + obj[i].email + "</td>";
            var td4 = "<td>" + obj[i].phone + "</td>";
            var td5 = "<td>" + obj[i].status + "</td></tr>";
            $("#usersdata").append(tr + td0 + td1 + td2 + td3 + td4 + td5);

        }

    }
});
```

Comment: Displays this message in the console. "Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'length' of undefined"

Comment: you have to add `dataType:'json',` in your ajax @BlakeTucker like `type : 'POST',
    url : 'scripts/search-user-script.php',
dataType:'json',`

Comment: @guardio: I added the dataType: 'json' and it worked. It now returns values. Thanks alot.

Answer (score 3):

Your ajax call return a String. You need to parse it into an `Object` before use it.

Try `obj = JSON.parse(obj)` before your `for` loop.

Like :

```
function(obj) {
  obj = JSON.parse(obj); // Add this line
  $("#usersdata").html("");
  for (var i = 0; i < obj.length; i++) {
    var tr = "<tr>";
    var td0 = "<td>" + (i + 1) + "</td>";
    var td1 = "<td>" + obj[i]["fullname"] + "</td>";
    var td2 = "<td>" + obj[i]["gender"] + "</td>";
    var td3 = "<td>" + obj[i]["email"] + "</td>";
    var td4 = "<td>" + obj[i]["phone"] + "</td>";
    var td5 = "<td>" + obj[i]["status"] + "</td></tr>";
    $("#usersdata").append(tr + td0 + td1 + td2 + td3 + td4 + td5);

  }

}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try the following code,
Make sure that your json properties have values. it should not contain NULL Values.

```js
          
var obj = [{"fullname": "Fname Lname",
  "gender": "M"},{"fullname": "Name2 name",
  "gender": "F"}]


for (var i = 0; i < obj.length; i++) {
  
  
            var tr = "<tr>";
            var td0 = "<td>" + (i + 1) + "</td>";
            var td1 = "<td>" + obj[i].fullname + "</td>";
            var td2 = "<td>" + obj[i].gender + "</td>";
 
            $("#usersdata").append(tr + td0 + td1 + td2 );

        }
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.10.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
<table id="usersdata" > </table>
```

Comment: Then yo can try the above method !

Comment: `obj` must be string, not object.

Comment: He mentioned JSON Array

Comment: You must convert JSON to object instead of using object.

Comment: I think so. Because obj.length returns 92 (which is the total of the characters in the array including the braces and parentheses)

Comment: Can you please update the Question with the Obj data with more lines

Comment: I have tried with your data that you posted,. and working fine

Answer (score -1):

I tried your code and was able to see the *correct* output. I guess, you must be having some *errors*, see the console to check it.

Please find the [demo](https://jsfiddle.net/shashank2691/mp6ck31h/).

Refer to the code below:

**HTML:**

```
<table id="dataTable">

</table>
```

**JS:**

```
$(function() {
  var data = [{
    "fullname": "Frank Robsinga",
    "gender": "Male",
    "email": "lorem@234.com",
    "phone": "3243434343",
    "status": "1"
  }, {
    "fullname": "Lorem ipsum",
    "gender": "Male",
    "email": "lorem@123.com",
    "phone": "3445656565",
    "status": "2"
  }, {
    "fullname": "ex eam dictas",
    "gender": "Female",
    "email": "lorem@435.com",
    "phone": "87878676",
    "status": "1"
  }];

  for (i = 0; i < data.length; i++) {
    var tr = "<tr>";
    var td0 = "<td>" + (i + 1) + "</td>";
    var td1 = "<td>" + data[i]["fullname"] + "</td>";
    var td2 = "<td>" + data[i]["gender"] + "</td>";
    var td3 = "<td>" + data[i]["email"] + "</td>";
    var td4 = "<td>" + data[i]["phone"] + "</td>";
    var td5 = "<td>" + data[i]["status"] + "</td></tr>";
    $("#dataTable").append(tr + td0 + td1 + td2 + td3 + td4 + td5);

  }
});
```

**CSS:**

```
table {
  border-collapse: collapse;
}

table,
td {
  border: 1px solid;
}
```

Comment: You need to convert JSON data to object instead of using object.

Comment: @R3tep, then what is the need of down-voting here? The `url` of the `ajax` call is relative though.